# ¿Dónde colocar los archivos .php dentro del host?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

buenas tardes. Me sucede lo siguiente. 
Alquilé un host compartido, cuando migré los archivos y traté de cargar la página me encontré con el inconveniente de que la página principal y otras no encuentra algunos archivos que están un nivel atrás de public_html. Tengo organizado mi proyecto de la siguiente manera.

raiz/public_html
-index.php
-biblioteca.html

raiz/php
-procesarComentarios.php

Cuando intento llamar desde biblioteca.html a procesarComentarios.php mediante Ajax(desde dentro de método Js) con la siguiente instrucción:

```
obj.open('GET', '../php/procesarComentarios.php', true);
```

no me carga el archivo. Intenté colocar de varias maneras el Path pero no puedo leer al .php. Se me ocurrió la idea de pasar TODOS los php a public_html para ver si era error en mi código pero no tengo errores. Hay conexión entre Ajax y php pero dentro de public_html.

**Nota 1:** En mi servidor local con Xampp también puedo acceder al .php con Ajax desde .html en carpetas fuera de public_html (se me ocurre que es por la configuración por defecto que trae Xampp, es más permisivo que un servidor privado).

**Nota 2:** Creé en el servidor alquilado un archivo .js (en raíz) fuera de public_html, intenté acceder desde index y las .html y tampoco tengo lectura.

Que estoy haciendo mal?
Donde debería colocar los archivos php dentro del host?

Según tengo entendido que dentro de public_html va lo que se quiere que sea publico. Pero si coloco los archivos .php dentro de public_html creo que estaría mal en cuanto a seguridad o tal vez estoy muy equivocado.

De antemano gracias...

Comment: Todo los recursos que tengas que acceder desde el navegador o desde un Ajax, tienen que estar en algún lado dentro de public, si o si, lo demás puede estar fuera. En cuanto a la seguridad, lo ideal es lo menos posible en public.

Comment: "tienen que estar en algún lado dentro de public, si o si, lo demás puede estar fuera." No tienía eso del todo claro, pensé que era algo que yo estaba haciendo incorrecto. Muchas gracias.